# Can't center objects in HTML

Tags: html, image, object

I want to put these two objects next to each other.
Here is what I currently have for my body.

I want this on the far left side of the sceen.

```
<h2><font color="#0101DF"><font face="Verdana">The Lastest Videos</font></h2>
<div class="fadein">
<img src="minecraft zombie.png">
<img src="Minecraft Clipart Edited.png">
<img src="Thumbnail.png">
</div>
```

I want this on the far right side of the sceen.

```
<div style="text-align: right;">
<h2><font color="#0101DF"><font face="Verdana">Top 10 Free To Play Games</font></h2>
<h4><font color="#9933CC"><font face="Verdana">#1 PlanetSide 2</font></h2>
<h4><font color="#9933CC"><font face="Verdana">#1 PlanetSide 2</font></h2>
<h4><font color="#9933CC"><font face="Verdana">#1 PlanetSide 2</font></h2>
</div>
```

But I want both objects to be next to each other.
I know its a bit confusing, sorry I don't know how to explain it very well.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `float:left` and `float:right` respectively.  Also, you should stop using the `font` tag.

Comment: What font tag are you talking about

Comment: All of them, the `font` tag is bad practice for several reasons.  Most notably it has been deprecated in HTML4 and unsupported in HTML5.  You would do better to find an appropriate tag (maybe `span`) and set the font/color via CSS.

Comment: also going from `h2` straight to `h4` is bad practice, and says you are using `h4`s for the font size, which is even worse practice.

Answer (score 2):

You could float them as in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3JTmz/).

```
<div style="float: left; ">
<!-- stuff on the left -->
</div>

<div style="float: right;">
<!-- stuff on the right -->
</div>

<!-- Just make sure you clear the floats.  -->
```

Comment: I tried that but then their still under each other, I need them next to each other.

Comment: Does the Fiddle I shared not behave as expected?  What's the width of your browser?  If they won't both fit, then one will drop below the other.  You can give them both fixed widths to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can move `<div>`s left and right by using `float: left;` and `float: right;`.

If your problem is that your `<h2>` and `<h4>` appear on separate lines, you can force them on the same line using `dispaly: inline-block`.

So try something like

```
<div style="float: left;">
  <h2><font color="#0101DF"><font face="Verdana">The Lastest Videos</font></h2>
  <div class="fadein">
    <img src="minecraft zombie.png">
    <img src="Minecraft Clipart Edited.png">
    <img src="Thumbnail.png">
  </div>
</div>
<div style="float: right;">
  <h2 style="display:inline-block;"><font color="#0101DF"><font face="Verdana">Top 10 Free To Play Games</font></h2>
  <h4 style="display:inline-block;"><font color="#9933CC"><font face="Verdana">#1 PlanetSide 2</font></h2>
  <h4 style="display:inline-block;"><font color="#9933CC"><font face="Verdana">#1 PlanetSide 2</font></h2>
  <h4 style="display:inline-block;"><font color="#9933CC"><font face="Verdana">#1 PlanetSide 2</font></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind that layouts in HTML are simply boxes. If you can think like that, you can achieve anything.

So the first thing you need is a BIG box so you can move LITTLE boxes around it with ease. So with that in mind, I created a container div and put two divs within it. Each with a specification of width thus making them 'Columns'. If you were to try the code below, you will get what you asked for.

```
<div class="container">
<div id="left" style="width: 49%; float: left; display: block;">
<!-- left -->
<h2 style="color: #0101DF; font-family: Verdana">The Lastest Videos</h2>
<img src="minecraft zombie.png">
<img src="Minecraft Clipart Edited.png">
<img src="Thumbnail.png">
</div>

<div id="right" style="width: 49%; float: right; display: block;">
<!-- right -->
<h2 style="color: #0101DF; font-family: Verdana">Top 10 Free To Play Games</h2>
<h4 style="color: #9933CC; font-family: Verdana">#1 PlanetSide 2</h4>
<h4 style="color: #9933CC; font-family: Verdana">#1 PlanetSide 2</h4>
<h4 style="color: #9933CC; font-family: Verdana">#1 PlanetSide 2</h4>
</div>

<!-- end container -->
</div>
```

If this isn't what you are after, can you expand on the question or perhaps provide a screenshot/photoshopped image on what you are trying to achieve?

Anyway, HTML is super easy! Chuck in some CSS and you'll be sweet (i've converted your code to have CSS replacements instead of the nasty  stuff!